# template function matching in g++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, matching

I'm having an odd problem, and am wondering why g++ 4.1.2 is behaving the way it does.

Stripped to its essentials:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
inline void f(T x) { std::cout << x*x; }

namespace foo {
  class A {
  public:
    void f() const { f(2); }
  };
}
```

The call to `f(2)` fails because the compiler fails to match the template function `f`.
I can make it work with `::f(2)` but I would like to know WHY this is necessary, since it's completely unambiguous, and as far as my (admittedly out of date) knowledge of the matching rules goes, this should work.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Is that relevant? Isn’t this behaviour strictly according to the standard?

Comment: @Konrad: I don't know, but I would have assumed not!  Surely both f()s are in scope at the call; since `foo::A::f()` has the wrong number of arguments, it should be removed from the set of "viable" functions...?

Comment: Konrad, why is this standard behavior?  Is number of arguments not the primary means for matching?

Comment: It turns out the namespace and the template are red herrings.  This doesn't work without them:

Comment: Other answers have it covered: This is the same lookup rule that makes it impossible to override just one function overload in a derived class: got to do them all if you do one.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: no they are not, not only is there a namespace, but there is also the class scope itself.

Comment: @Konrad: You're quite right!  Funny that I knew about a name in a derived class hiding a name in the base class, but not this... :)

Comment: @Dov : Also check out my answer. I have added relevant quote from the C++ Standard.

Comment: A simple workaround for not having to qualify each use is adding a `using ::f` in your function body. That will bring the global namespace `f` into the scope of the function, where it will become a candidate together with `foo::A::f`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler examines all scopes for a candidate, starting with the current scope. It finds a function named `f` in the immediate scope, **and there stops the search**. Your template version is never examined as a candidate.

See [Namespaces and the Interface Principle](http://gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm) for a complete explanation.

Comment: +1 and great link.  All those Sutter's Mill articles are fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to C++03 section

> 3.4.1  Unqualified name lookup
>
> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**.  If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

In your code sample the compiler finds a name `f` in the current scope thus ending the unqualified name lookup but there is a mismatch in the prototypes of the functions and so you get an error.

Qualifying it with `::` makes it work because the name is then searched in the global namespace and the `f` with the correct prototype is called.

Comment: Another possibility, bringing the name into scope explicitly `using ::f; f(2);`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the compiler is trying to call A::f and fails because of the argument, which seems normal in a way. Do you have the same error if you use a non template function ?

Comment: It turns out the namespace and the template are red herrings.  
#include <iostream>

void f(int x) { std::cout << x*x; }

class A {
public:
  void f() const { f(2); }
};